# Unable to display statistics in the graph note() parameter

Tags: stata

I want to display the total count of the data in the graph `note()`.

I tried the following:

```
note(count)
```

However, this just displays the literal word "count".

I also tried to create a local variable but I am having difficulty just initializing it.

While I can do the following:

```
. local N = 100
. di `N'
100
```

I can't seem to do:

```
. local N = count
count not found
```

Comment: The error is signalled by Stata; it doesn't know what you mean by `count` although if you had a variable with that name you would have found that the value of `count[1]` was used and if you had a scalar of that name, it would have been used. Although you tell us nothing about your data, that is why you get an error. `count` being a command name does not imply that the name is also the name of any result.

Comment: Note "local macros" are always so called. Macros in Stata are not considered variables, regardless of whether they correspond to what would be called variables in other languages.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts for how to merge your different accounts.

Comment: I see 20 accounts with the name "Cody Smith". I guess it's a fairly common name....

Comment: So how do I create a variable that's not an entire column, like I would in say Python?

Comment: A local macro, a global macro, a scalar, a string scalar, a matrix are all available in Stata to do things with, and there are classes too, and there's Mata. I don't know anything about Python to comment on what you do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of observations is kept in `_N` but it is not necessarily the number of observations used in a graph.

The command `count` displays a result and leaves a saved result, the number counted, in its wake as `r(N)`. This is documented both in the `help` for count and in the manual entry.

Hence you can verify that this sequence leaves a note `74 observations` in the resulting graph.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. count if mpg < .
  74

. histogram mpg, note(`r(N)' observations)
(bin=8, start=12, width=3.625)
```

Note that no r-class command should intervene here between `count` and your use of its result. r-class saved results, like any other saved results, are overwritten easily. In many circumstances you are well advised, as you did, to store the result in a local macro, say by

```
. local N = r(N)
```

immediately after the `count` command and then refer to that later in the `note()`.

This is a more general method because `count` by itself returns the number of observations and so can be used when this is directly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! This method combined with the Spencer's method is also useful for storing multiple conditional counts as well.

Comment: @CodySmith Nick's answer is more flexible but note that this is not what you asked in your original question. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PearlySpencer is right. I lean a bit more to answering  a better question and explaining why you should think a bit differently. Pearly is more about answering what you asked and letting you ask a different question later.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of observations is stored in `_N`.

```
sysuse auto, clear
display _N
74
```

So the following works for me:

```
local N = _N 
twoway scatter mpg price, note(Total no of observations: `N')
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the other answers, I ultimately did:

```
count
local N = r(N)
count if male
local N_male = r(N)
count if !male
local N_female = r(N)
...
note("N = `N'" "       `N_male' (Male)" "       `N_female' (Female)")
```

But still can't get the commas to render at the thousands and millions place.

Comment: `local N_male : display %9.0fc r(N)` will push the result through some formatting. See `help macro`. and `help extended_fcn`.